# select child element of specific parent

Tags: html, css

I have the different classes in each page of body tag and I used css for #top div within the body tag

```
<body class="one">
<div id="top"></div>
</body>

#top{
  /*css code here*/
}
```

I want to use same css instead of class `.one` something like this:

```
#top:not(.one){
/*css code here*/
}
```

more clearly I want to apply the same css for all pages for #top but not to the page which body class is `.one`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot) selector on the parent, not on the child.

```
body:not(.one) #top {
    /*css code here*/
}
```

- P.S - You should notice this selector have some browser support issues as you can see [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=not).

Comment: Ooops! it is not supported at least IE8

Comment: Yep. You can make it the default setting for `#top` and override the unwanted settings for `.one #top` instead.

Comment: I think I should use jquery for this.

Comment: Yeah override would be better than jquery.

Comment: You're right. It's advisable to use jQuery for design purposed when it can be easily made with pure CSS.